# Mark all selected columns after SELECT Statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am selecting a random selection of a table and want to mark the selected columns. I have an 'exported' column which is binary and is set 0 by default. When selecting it I want it to become 1. I thought of combining a SELECT and INSERT statement like:

```
SELECT  id, status, vorname, nachname, strasse, hnr, plz, ort, telefon1, telefon2  
FROM adressen 
WHERE (vorname LIKE ? OR nachname LIKE ?) 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ?

AND INSERT INTO adressen (exported) VALUES '1'
```

but this seems to be not the right approach. The select statement works perfectly fine just as I want it to be but I don't know how to set the exported column to 1 for every selected row. Since the data is selected randomly I can't just do an insert statement after it since it won't match the same selected ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the results in a temporary table and then use `update`:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_results AS
    SELECT id, status, vorname, nachname, strasse, hnr, plz, ort, telefon1, telefon2  
    FROM adressen 
    WHERE (vorname LIKE ? OR nachname LIKE ?) 
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT ?;
```

Then:

```
update adressen a join
       temp_results r
       on a.id = r.id
    set exported = 1;
```

Note:  This assumes that `id` is unique.  If it is not, use the primary key on the table.

I also suspect that your query probably wants something like `exported = 0`.